# ResourceLoader - ResourceMap Not Found and other problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, localization

my Team Project (UWP App in C#) is offered in two languages (de-DE and en-US).

The project has a **Resources.resw** file stored in

```
"Model\DataManager\ResourcesManager\Language\de-DE\"
```

which contains all the strings that related to the GUI.

For my part i need to handle specific tasks differently based on the language of the App, but the problem is, neither me nor my team knows how to really work with the **resourceloader**.

I have the following problems:

1) I was told that the resourceloader gets automatically the windows language and use it in the app if it is available, otherwise App default will be used.
What i was also told is that this cannot be changed internally, even if the user wants that (like in the settings page or so) and the only solution is to change the windows language. is this true? if not how can it be done?

2) For my part i need to know the current language of the App but i don't know how and i also need to store the language related strings in an appropriate resources file.
I tried to define a new file named LPResources.resw where i added all the strings like:

```
DBQueryGenerator_DateInterpreter_month-12 means December in the English version.
```

But trying to access this string with:

```
ResourceLoader resources = new ResourceLoader("LPResources");
```

or

```
ResourceLoader resources = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("LPResources");
```

and then

```
resources.GetString("DBQueryGenerator_DateInterpreter_month-01")
```

throws directly an exception **ResourceMap Not Found.**

I tried to search for a solution but i couldn't find any helpful information.

If you can answer one of the questions or both i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) I was told that the resourceloader gets automatically the windows language and use it in the app if it is available, otherwise App default will be used. What i was also told is that this cannot be changed internally, even if the user wants that (like in the settings page or so) and the only solution is to change the windows language. is this true? if not how can it be done?

This is not very accurate. The resources that Windows loads for your app and also the language(s) used to format dates, times, numbers, and other components are determined by the app runtime language list and it is made up of these items:

1. (Optional) Primary Language Override.
2. The user's languages that are supported by the app.
3. If 1 and 2 are empty, then the default or first language supported by the app.

The detailed information is introduced in this document: [Understand user profile languages and app manifest languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/manage-language-and-region#qualify-resource-files-with-their-language).

> 2) For my part i need to know the current language of the App but i don't know how and i also need to store the language related strings in an appropriate resources file. I tried to define a new file named LPResources.resw.

As the reply above, to get the current language, you should get the app runtime language list, you can get it use the following three ways.

```
//First way
string runtimeLanguages = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues["Language"];

//Second way
IReadOnlyList<string> runtimeLanguages1 = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Languages;

//Third way
var runtimeLanguages2 = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages;
```

Then you can make a simple judgement to get the what the user sees in the app. (Of course, you should read and understand the [Understand user profile languages and app manifest languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/manage-language-and-region#qualify-resource-files-with-their-language) document firstly.)

For getting the resource, I tried the code,

```
var Loader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("LPResources");
var text1 = Loader.GetString("DBQueryGenerator_DateInterpreter_month-12");
```

It can return the defined text value, please check you resource file name and make sure it is correct.

**Note**: "LPResources" is the LPResources.resw file, and "DBQueryGenerator_DateInterpreter_month-12" is the resource string `Name`.

You can also use the following code to get the resource,

```
ResourceMap resourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("LPResources");
ResourceContext resourceContext = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
var str = resourceMap.GetValue("DBQueryGenerator_DateInterpreter_month-12", resourceContext).ValueAsString;
```

**Note that**: Whether the LPResources.resw file is in the project's root directory or in a folder of the project, you can call it using its name directly.

Comment: thank you very much for the helpful reply.
The first method to get the resource didn't work. It gave me the same problem with the resource map.

I implemented the second method like this:

        ResourceMap resourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("LPResources");
        ResourceContext resourceContext = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();

Comment: With the following function:

            private bool Foo(string someInput)
        {
            if(someInput.Equals(GetValue("DBQueryGenerator_DateInterpreter_today")){
return true;
}
return false;
        }

            private string GetValue(string id)
        {
            return resourceMap.GetValue(id, resourceContext).ValueAsString;
        }

But i'm getting now this exception:
-  Exception Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Model.dll ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Thank you very much!
After a long time of googling we changed the structure of the solution from multiple projects in the solution with references to a single project (with all the components of model, view and presenter).
Then i tried the mentioned methods above and the second one worked!
I'm sorry i can't vote for your answer, because im still new to stackoverflow but your solution works like a charm.
Thanks a lot :-)